# SceneKit: Ruler Tick Mark / Number Rendering

Tags: ios, graphics, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I'm working on an ARKit/SceneKit Ruler app and I'm trying to render the ruler's tick marks and numbers as a texture. The ruler is of variable length and can change on the fly.

What's a good way of render the numbers and tick marks? Right now we're using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and doing a

```
ctx.fill(CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 8))
```

but it seems like not a great solution. The tick marks seem possibly easier to use an image texture with, but what about the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numbers you could use [SCNText](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntext). If you'll set `extrusionDepth` to zero, you'll get plane text. And for marks you could use [SCNPlane](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnplane). Both of them have one-sided materials by default, which means that back side will be invisible.